# C# converting xsd to ConfigurationSection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, configuration-files

I am using Visual-Studio-2012

I am using ConfigurationSection class for declaring a new customized configuration section in app.config.

I need to use that in most efficient way, so:

1. Using the Intellisense feature, so when I am writing a code in app.config, there will be automatic detection of the sections, and element collections tags.
   I have check that out, and find that XSD may be a solution for that.
2. I want to auto-generate a class from xsd file (with the relevant code, using ConfigurationSection, ConfigurationProperty, etc.) - Otherwise, I need to create a template file (with relevant tags) from the ConfigurationSection class.

How can I do the above?
If I cannot - What is the best way creating?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. XSD shall be used.

   Using the Intellisense feature is done by opening the XSD file and in properties choose the schema.
2. I have found that adding the class of ConfigurationSection is a good attitude.